# Is it right to edit a question and make it totally different?

Tags: discussion

I see in this site users can edit the questions asked by other users and, sometimes, the editor changes the question so that it becomes totally different to the original. Is that right? I think every edit must be approved by the original author of the question. Or is there any way to make other users stay away from the question you asked?

Comment: No, that's not right; neither the OP nor any other editors should completely change the Q, as that breaks existing As. However, the two solutions you suggest are impractical. If you see this, and don't have the rep to roll it back yourself, flag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't right. Neither the OP nor any other editors should completely change the question.

If they have something different to ask, they should ask a new question.