# Are there guidelines for what should/should not be edited?

Tags: discussion, edits

I posted an answer to a question, and when I returned to it I was dumbfounded by what I saw. My description was no longer my own. It had been completely re-written by another user.

Is this acceptable?? I understand when small grammatical errors or formatting improvements should be made. But completely rewriting an explanation??

[Here's the revision in question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32742984/revisions#rev-arrow-7f3f80ac-6720-4144-b278-e37e042a366e).

Comment: Editing is for correcting mistakes and minor clarifications. It is not for rewriting posts.

Comment: Related: [Is it right to edit a question and make it totally different?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306584/is-it-right-to-edit-a-question-and-make-it-totally-different/306588#306588) The answer is no. Same goes for answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I agree that the edit was inappropriate, for two very big reasons:

- It did not appear to *improve* the answer appreciably. The first paragraph was reworded, but not in a way that *clearly* and *significantly* improves the clarity, nor adds significant new information.
- It *changes* the answer. The original answer limits the changes of height and width to the one element in question. The edit modifies this to effect that change on *all* elements of that class (`profile_pic`).

Either of these reasons would be cause for a rollback, but the latter is particularly egregious. There is nothing in the question that would lead a reader to believe that the height and width changes must be applied to the entire class. *Maybe* it should be, but doing so is not a given nor does failing to do so detract from the original answer.

Someone who feels that the actual code in an answer should be different, where the original answer's code is not clearly *wrong* per se (e.g. has a serious bug that is inconsistent with the answer author's intent), should be adding a new answer themselves, providing detailed explanation for why the differences in their answer are important.

This does two important things: it preserves the original, correct answer for future readers, and it enhances knowledge (potentially) by providing a clear contrast of differing opinions and justification for that difference.

Rolling back to the previous edit was entirely appropriate here. That said, I would refrain from rolling back edits, even on your own posts, unless you can articulate in a clear, specific way why the edit was inappropriate (failing to improve the answer is a perfectly legitimate basis for a rollback, so the bar is not very high here). The default attitude should IMHO be to accept edits; give the editor the benefit of the doubt, until you can (at least to yourself) clearly state why the edit should not be accepted.

Finally note that rolling back edits may get you into a tug-of-war; I would roll-back only once. If the author of the edit persists, that's the time to bring a moderator into the mix. Remember to stay professional and polite to everyone involved, including the edit's author (as you have here).

Answer (score 21):

No, it's not acceptable. See the [Edit Questions And Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

Only by looking at the difference I can almost immediately tell that the edit is invalid. After looking in more depth, I can confirm that it's invalid.

The user who edited your post violated many of the above. I rolled back to the previous version.

Comment: A lot of high rep users tend to do this... What if revisions are also applicable to high rep users but less votes are needed for it to be approved?

Comment: Granted the editor changed a lot, but what he changed explained more of the "why" the answer worked.  Why is that a bad thing?

Comment: Edits shouldn't change the whole intention of the OP. It feels like a new answer, not an edit. Also the code shouldn't be touched (unless it's a typo, and even then, I prefer to notify the author, not to edit his post).

Comment: @edrodriguez: The user that made this edit had 2k privileges. No one approved it. The rules (for the most part) are the same for all editors, though.

Comment: thats what I'm saying, that everyone has to have their edit reviewed, it would just depend on a number of revisions depending user rep @NathanTuggy

Comment: @edrodriguez: Post that as a feature request then, but I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: I do think its a good idea, but it will not be well received in meta. Mostly by high reps. I just think it would give some fairness to the edit feature @NathanTuggy , glad we could dialogue over this.... :)

Comment: @edrodriguez The whole point of the reputation system is that you're trusted to make good judgement with new moderation tools. The restriction is quite low, so that people new to the site don't start making immediate edits without understanding how the site works. There's no reason to further fill up the review queues. That being said, someone who continually makes these kinds of edits could be flagged for moderation intervention.

Comment: @edrodriguez: I've never seen a high-rep user make a stupid edit like this. Can you point me to some examples? Perhaps you're missing the subtleties involved here, confusing this case with those where a post has been substantively improved by a high-rep user _without changing the original author's intention_, which is encouraged.

Comment: Sorry, I left my *Save every single question, JUST IN CASE* bag at home @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Besides, even if I kept record of all of this, it wouldn't matter. HighRep users master race :)

Answer (score -7):

As per the [help center article on editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) you should edit for the following reasons:

> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

From the looks of the edit, the editor was doing mostly number 2 and 5, just trying to make the meaning more clear, including more *why* the answer works and adding links to the docs.

That being said, it's your post and you can rollback the edit and change it as you see fit (within reason).

For an edit like that, I don't see it as being a bad thing (since it just makes the answer better by explaining the why it works).  It might have been better as a separate answer though.

Comment: But rewriting the answer it's beyond an edit I believe. Also, *added 115 characters in body* doesn't quite explain as to why the answer had to be completely reworded

Comment: @edrodriguez I'm less concerned with how many characters it took to make the answer better as *if* it made the answer better.  (Could he have done it in a less invasive way?  Probably.  Does that mean it was worthless and we should throw out the baby with the bath water? I don't think so.)  The original was more of a "if you foo the bar it will work".  The edit explained why foo-ing the bar makes it work so that the problem and solution is less black magic.

Comment: An edit should not take OP's ownership of the answer. If your edit is practically your own answer, just post it as an answer.