# Is it reasonable to roll back drastic changes in the question?

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

Two weeks ago I answered this question: [Column features must be of type ... but was actually ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49726809/8371915). The question looked valid and OP seemed to be satisfied, and accepted the answer.

Today, I found the OP completely rewrote the post ([rewritten version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49726809/3) vs. [original](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49726809/1)) asking a completely unrelated question.

I decided to roll back to the previous version and leave a comment. Is this an acceptable solution?

Comment: Yea, completely changing the question like that isn't acceptable. Rolling it back is the right course of action.

Comment: Yeah.. Users get rate-limited or question-banned, then they start with this kind of activity:(

Comment: Yay! People are finally listening to https://twitter.com/eviloverflow/status/987278498183221248 and https://twitter.com/eviloverflow/status/979745217518686208!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I would consider this an acceptable solution.

[This meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306584/7296893) explains that editing to ask a different question is not acceptable.

Note that people who are banned or rate-limited from asking new questions might use this approach to try to ask a new question anyway. If an edit war sparks, you can get moderators involved. Unfortunately, it's not possible to rollback the unaccept of your answer.